# Show Application Launcher Check box For Wix Installer After Repair

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

I was able to successfully launch application [Following this guide](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install/). But this check box does not appear for the repair option.

```
<Publish Dialog="ExitDialog"
         Control="Finish" 
         Event="DoAction" 
         Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
```

I tried few changes with condition **WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed** but the check box does not appear, even after removing the *and NOT Installed* condition also it does not appear.

Is it not the same ExitDialog Dialog shows in wix after a repair !
Do I need to put a correct condition for the same ?

Already went through few
[WiX: Can't handle "Launch an application after install" checkbox = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272275/wix-cant-handle-launch-an-application-after-install-checkbox-0)

[Wix installer - conditionally display "Launch application" on ExitDialog based on custom dialog input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284731/wix-installer-conditionally-display-launch-application-on-exitdialog-based-o)

[Wix - How to run exe files after installation from installed directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19271862/wix-how-to-run-exe-files-after-installation-from-installed-directory)

https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install/

[image: Repair Mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox itself is defined inside WixUI with that condition, so you'd have to replace `ExitDialog` itself to replace the condition.

Comment: Are you saying that <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog"
         Control="Finish" 
         Event="DoAction" 
         Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
This line does not at all affect it ! So i can remove it but need to re create the dialog itself ! Is there any such documentation available for this !

Comment: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations/